# How would I go about counting the number of consonants in a word? python

Tags: python

In python, how would I go about counting the number of consonants in a word? I realize there are a couple different ways to do this, but I think my way of choice would be to analyze each letter of a word and add to a counter when I encounter a consonant.  I just can't figure out how to implement it.

Something starting with this?

```
count = 0
consonant = 'astringofconsonants'
if consonant in string[0]:
    count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, your answers gave me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start you have given is not very pythonic.

Try iterating through the list using

```
for c in word:
    if c in consonants:
        # do something
```

You could also use a generator like the following. It will go through each letter and count the number of each consonant is in the word.

```
(word.count(c) for c in consonants)
```

use the `sum()`  function to add them all up

Comment: Speaking of Pythonic, I think you mean `list`, not `array` ;)

Comment: ahhh yes sorry getting mixed up with other languages

Comment: I always read "Pythonic" as "far less suitable for beginners" :-)

Comment: hahhaha Yeah because most beginners would come from a C/Java background probably

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over strings the same way you iterate over a list:

```
for letter in word:
  if letter in consonants:
    # You can fill in from here
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a string yields each character in turn.

```
for c in 'thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog':
    print c
```

Answer (score 1):

Comprehensions!

```
count = sum(1 for c in cons if c not in ['a','e','i','o','u'])
```

From comments, probably more Pythonic:

```
count = len([c for c in cons if c not in 'aeiou'])
```

Comment: That's actually not a (Python) comprehension.

Comment: Or why not just, len([c for c in word if not in ['a','e','i','o','u']])

Comment: I'd replace the list with `'aeiou'`: `count = len([letter for letter in word if letter not in 'aeiou'])`

Comment: Thanks for the extra suggestions :) constructs like these keep making Python my favorite language.